# Update a field based on multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make my experience bar update the value properly by checking if the xp value of the user is bigger than the max xp for his level. I am increasing the value by this code

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE progression SET xp=(xp + 2) WHERE username='$username'";
```

And then i would like to check in the database if the value of xp now is higher than the max xp and if it is take xp - max xp. This should make it so if a player is at etc 98% xp and gets 10% xp it should update to 8% on the next level ( if there is no increase in max xp for next level). I would like something like this, but this does not seem to work.

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE if xp > maxxp SET xp=(xp - maxxp) WHERE username='$username'";
```

Comment: That's not how `if` works in mysql. But you can just add another condition to the `WHERE` section.

Comment: if you want to compare, then why are you using UPDATE? you need to run a SELECT, so where's that?

Comment: *"This should make it so if a player is at etc 98% xp and gets 10% xp it should update to 8% on the next level"* - I think you're going about this from the wrong approach in the first place.  Most systems would simply record the total number of experience points earned.  Any additional experience simply increments that total.  When showing things like levels or percentage complete to the next level, those are simple calculations performed on the fly.  Don't store the calculations.  Store the *data* and perform the calculations in the display.

Comment: @jeroen and how would that condition look like?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because i want to update the value IF the xp is bigger than max xp? changed title also. Thanks.

Comment: @David i havent thought of that approach, perhaps that would be a lot smoother in the long run when it gets more advanced.

Comment: I'm curious; why are your other questions with what look to me as solutions, weren't marked as solved? including this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has a wrong syntax since you don't need an extra if:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE if xp > maxxp SET xp=(xp - maxxp) WHERE username='$username'";
```

should be

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE progression SET xp=(xp - maxxp) WHERE username='$username' AND xp > maxxp";
```

but I agree with David that you should just update the number of experience points and do the level calculation on the fly.

Also note that in this query you are missing the name of the table to be updated. I assume you are still updating progression.

Furthermore, try to have a look to prepared statements: this will prevent SQL injections.

Comment: this works thank you, but unfortunately it created other issues so would you mind explaining what you and David mean with doing the calculation on the fly?

Comment: let's say you get a new level each 100 points. You store in db 325 point and you calculate in php (or whatever else) that you are level 3 + 25 points. In this case you use modulus of (325/100)=3.25 so the modulus is 3 and what remains is 0.25 that again *100 = 25 points. This is more important if you do vary the threshold for each level (1st 100, second after other 250). Is it more clear?

Comment: Yeah a bit more clear. But since im very new to this it's still a lot which is not clear. 1st, where should this calculation take place? i also do vary the threshold by increasing the max xp required each level by * 1.5. Atm for example the first level need 10 points which is equal to 100% of the experience bar.

Comment: I just gave you a simple hint on this. But you need to do it on the front end (php or any other language) your page is written on and not on the db. Why don't you try elaborating on this and start with some new questions when you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 2 queries for this, you can calculate it directly using the [modulus](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod):

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE progression SET xp = (xp + 2) % maxxp WHERE username = :username";
```

Also note that you should not inject variables in your queries but use a prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses `CASE` statements similar to how other languages use `IF` statements. So I believe you are instead looking for something SIMILAR to;

```
CASE WHEN (xp > maxxp) THEN SET xp=(xp - maxxp) WHERE username='$username'
```

Check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) for more info on CASE statements within SQL. But as others have mentioned; you could easily add another condition to your where statement to solve this issue.

AND; you should never pass variables directly into SQL statements as this is a security issue. Instead you should bind parameters to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, if you want to use an IF.

```
UPDATE  progression 
SET     xp = IF(xp > maxxp, xp - maxxp, xp)
WHERE   username='$username'
```

But maybe, a solution with a WHERE can be better.